# Where does the redux store live?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this React Redux app, and I was using `composeWithDevTools` to make the redux store available for debugging in the browser. Now I have disabled that package for production and I was wondering where the redux store is. Is possible for someone to actually see the store somewhere in the browser cache/storage etc?

Can somebody shed some light on this matter?

Comment: The store is just a regular JS object in memory. It's not actually persistently 'stored' anywhere

Comment: The store is just a javascript object that can be inspected with a debugger. That means everybody that has a little knowledge in debugging javascript code can look into the store pretty easily. It's not suitable to have any secrets stored there. But this is basically true for everything in your javascript code.

Comment: Don't you ever use createStore from redux to instantiate/create it?

Comment: @Aron thank you. For someone with js knowledge as you said, would it be easy to modify it? I don't have any secrets stored in there, but I do have an admin boolean which lets the user access the admin panel. There are more checks on the server to not let someone who isn t truly an admin modify anything even if the store is modified, but I was just wondering.

Comment: @Xlee Yes, I do.

Comment: @BogdanDaniel by modify do you mean modify through the console or devtools? I'd say not unless you expose it by making it a global variable by doing for example `window.store = store`

Comment: @Aron yes, that's what I meant. Cause I don't get what security is in place for the user not to be able to mess with something that is stored within the browser. Any useful tutorials/website on how to inspect these javascript objects? I'm really curious about what's happening.

Comment: @BogdanDaniel You need to assume that anyone could change anything in the store at any time. So a user with malicious intent could *see* the admin user's UI for example, but should never be able to see sensitive data - because the server only provides it to "true" admins. The nature of single page apps is that you can in fact inspect the entire app and see what admins would see, etc. but that's ok as long as the server handles auth and permissions.

Comment: @timotgl Got it. Thank you.